# system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception a task was canceled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

My code to fetch a huge set of data from an API is like this

```
public static async Task<model> GetDataAsyncs(string url)
    {
        // Initialization.  
        mymodel responseObj = new mymodel();

        using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
            using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
            {
                // Setting Base address.  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBasicUri);

                // Setting content type.                   
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // Initialization.  
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

                // HTTP Get  
                response = await client.GetAsync(url ).ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Verification  
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Reading Response.  
                    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    responseObj.Status = true;
                    responseObj.Data = result;
                }
            }
        }


        return responseObj;
    }
```

And I am calling above function like this inside my controller

```
public ActionResult myActionMethod()
        {
            string res= helper.GetDataAsync("url").Result.Data;
        }
```

Ocassionally this throws an error `system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception a task was canceled`  . This does not occurs every time. Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: When the client (the browser) cancels the request (for example, the "stop" button is clicked in the browser), the server will stop processing the request by throwing a `TaskCanceledException`. Could that be what's happening?

Comment: @GabrielLuci No, No user action is happening after page starts loading

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for sure why this is happening, but there are some red flags in your code that can be cleaned up and might resolve this.

The first is your use of `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. It can cause some unintended consequences, so I suggest you don't use it. I talk about it more in [an article I recently wrote](https://www.gabescode.com/dotnet/2022/02/04/dont-use-configureawait.html).

Second, use `await` instead of `.Result` whenever possible, which is almost always. Using `.Result` can also cause unintended, hard-to-debug consequences. In your code, I see no reason you can't use `await`.

Third, [the documentation of `HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks) says:

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors.

So you can declare a static `HttpClient` and reuse that every time you need it.

Fourth, there's no need for this line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
```

You're instantiating a new `HttpResponseMessage` here, but then immediately overwriting it in the next line.

Making those changes, your code could look like this:

```
private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(
    new HttpClientHandler {ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; }}
) {
    BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBasicUri),
    DefaultRequestHeaders = {
        Accept = { new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json") }
    }
};

public static async Task<model> GetDataAsyncs(string url)
{
    mymodel responseObj = new mymodel();

    var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseObj.Status = true;
        responseObj.Data = result;
    }
    
    return responseObj;
}
```

And then change your controller action to be `async` and use `await`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> myActionMethod()
{
    var res = (await helper.GetDataAsync("url")).Data;
}
```

See if you still end up getting exceptions after making those changes.